# DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH Bulk Fetch

Tags: oracle, migration, plsql

i have question about  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH geting result set without stored_procedure
i have oracle and i have database link so i  am running this query `select * from table where id >20` via     `DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@dblinkname;` so when i am using fetch_row it is fetching one by one row so i want to get list of rows and insert it in 1 insert not while loop problem is that i can't use stored procedure on remote db server side so i have only select statment. maybe someone knows some answar (with pipeline i made it but it is kinda slow beacouse it always runs in while loop)

Comment: Just for sanity, the database you're on is Oracle but the remote database is some non-Oracle database, right?  Otherwise, you wouldn't use `dbms_hs_passthrough`, you'd just do `insert into local_table select * from table@dblinkname where id > 20`

Comment: yes other side mysql but there is json column and i have old odbc connection table@dblink not working for me beacouse i can't see json columns